# Get Parent Row from Child in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

From within a row in a child of a row in datatables, how do I find access the parent row in datatables. Basically, I would like to highlight the parent row when its child row after expansion is clicked.

I gave all parentRows a class name, and when a button in the child row is clicked, I did this:

```
var tr = $(this).prev('.parentRow');
tr.addClass('rowIsDirty');

<tr class="vcenter parentRow">
                    <td class="hidden">@element.ElementName</td>
                    <td class="details-control meter"></td>
                    <td>@element.ElementTemplateName</td>
                    <td>@element.ElementName</td>
                    <td>@element.MeterTemplateName</td>
                    <td>@element.MeterName</td>
                </tr>

<td class="details-control">@element.CaseDataPairs</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><b>@item.ProductName</b></td>
                        <td class="text-left">@item.ProductGroupName</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.VersionsCount</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("ProductView", "ProductManagement", new RouteValueDictionary(new {productId = item.ProductId}))" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary ui-tooltip details-Customer" id="ProductDetails"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                        </td>
                                               <td class="text-center">
                            <input checked="@item.IsActive" data-toggle="toggle" class="toggleCheckBox ActivateProductButton" data-style="ios" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" type="checkbox" id="EditAccountIsActive" data-product-id="@item.ProductId">
                        </td>

  $(document).on('change', '.ActivateProductButton, function() {
            UpdateStatus($(this));
        });

        function UpdateStatus(thisObj) {
            var tr = thisObj.closest('.parentRow');
            tr.removeClass('highlightExpanded');
            tr.addClass('rowIsDirty');
        }
```

It's not giving me the `parentRow` to highlight. Any ideas?

Comment: use `$(this).closest('.parentRow');`  - however, without seeing your HTML, it's hard to tell exactly

Comment: I'm using the example on the datatables website for expanding and collapsing rows to show child details.

Comment: Do you mind posting your HTML and / or creating a fiddle for your particular issue?  It makes the question self-sufficient and easier for everyone to troubleshoot.  (related: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It would be very difficult to post my html due to the structure and length. This is the example I used, only replacing it the child column items with button and handling the onclick event. The click event is called for certain.      https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()

Comment: It does not have to be *all* the code just the MCVE.. (read the link) - help me, help you!!

Comment: I have added more code to the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90065/discussion-between-ochi-and-james-makinde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a simplified version of a table and added an event to when a button is clicked...

Hopefully you will be able to modify this code to suit your needs.

The code selects the closest node with class `.parentRow` and, since the nested row is added as a sibling row, we select the previous row (`.prev()`) to mark as dirty (or highlight or whatever)

Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

```js
function UpdateStatus(thisObj) {
  var tr = thisObj.closest('.parentRow').prev();
  $(tr).removeClass('highlightExpanded');
  $(tr).addClass('rowIsDirty');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.UnitStatusButton').on('click', function() {
    UpdateStatus($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
.highlightExpanded {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.rowIsDirty {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr role="row" class="even shown">
    <td class=" details-control">iconhere</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Brielle Williamson</td>
    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>$372,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parentRow highlightExpanded">
    <td colspan="5">
      <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Full name:</td>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Extension number:</td>
            <td>4804</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Extra info:</td>
            <td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>
              <button class="UnitStatusButton">Click Me</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr role="row" class="even shown">
    <td class=" details-control">iconhere2</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Jane Williamson</td>
    <td>No Specialist</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>$2,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I eventually used.   var tr = thisObj.closest('table').closest('tr').prev();
            tr.removeClass('highlightExpanded');
            tr.addClass('rowIsDirty');